# Biber broken on debian wheezy/sid texlive 2011

Tags: texlive, biber, debian

After an update of texlive 2011 (two days ago), biber (version 0.9.9) is completely broken. The solution found via google (deleting directory /tmp/par-.....) does not work. The Error is:

```
~/Git/DISS$ biber -h
Can't load '/tmp/par-6772656269/cache-   ab06f20732bfab23dfa35f56998ad4edca61bee1/608da891.so' 
for module XML::LibXML: /tmp/par-6772656269/cache-ab06f20732bfab23dfa35f56998ad4edca61bee1/libz.so.1: 
version `ZLIB_1.2.3.3' not found (required by /usr/lib/../lib/libxml2.so.2) at /usr/local/perl/lib/5.14.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/DynaLoader.pm line 190.
 at /usr/local/perl/lib/site_perl/5.14.1/PAR/Heavy.pm line 120
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at XML/LibXML.pm line 153.
Compilation failed in require at XML/LibXML/Simple.pm line 16.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at XML/LibXML/Simple.pm line 16.
Compilation failed in require at Biber/LaTeX/Recode.pm line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Biber/LaTeX/Recode.pm line 9.
Compilation failed in require at Biber/Utils.pm line 21.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Biber/Utils.pm line 21.
Compilation failed in require at Biber/Internals.pm line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Biber/Internals.pm line 8.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 22) line 2.
...propagated at /usr/local/perl/lib/5.14.1/base.pm line 94.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Biber.pm line 5.
Compilation failed in require at script/biber line 20.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at script/biber line 20.
```

Any ideas how to get rid of that problem? I should finish my thesis instead of fighting biber errors ;-/

Thanks in advance!

#

Some further information after searching quite a while and texlive reinstallation:
biber searches in /usr/local/perl/lib/5.14.1/ which does not exist anymore after update. Thus, the error is related to a debian update and not the texlive update.

The problem now is that I do not have a clue where biber gets that path from. If I know that I can adjust the path and it sould work. If it is "hardcoded" I will try to make a symbolic link tomorrow

Comment: By the way, if you're finish your thesis, I strongly recommend you don't update TeX Live (or anything critical) on the machine you're using for that until your thesis is completed, unless you really know why you need the update (and even then, update only the specific package you need). Every update comes with a risk of breaking things.

Comment: Unless you really need version 0.9.9 of biber, you can downgrade it using `tlmgr` which makes backups before upgrades by default. Try `tlmgr restore biber` to see the list of revisions, then `tlmgr restore biber <number>` to restore to the given revision.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I called myself an idiot because I didn't make a backup. That is great news. As soon as I am back home I'll do that and freeze the system until submission of the thesis (I hoped to get an improved version of biblatex-chicago)

Comment: Sadly rolling back does not change anything. I guess it is related to my system update and not the new biber version =-(

Comment: The perl path you see is misleading - that is the path on the machine I built biber on. The binary version of biber needs no perl at all to run (it has its own internally. The issue is the zlib version for some reason. This is strange as biber should also contain its own, correct zlib version. The only libraries it uses from the OS are really fundamental ones like libc. I'll look into it a bit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. That saves me a lot of effort

Comment: It looks like you are using the 64-bit biber for linux - you are, I assume on 64-bit debian?

Comment: Please can you try the binary here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/testfiles/biber-linux_x86_64.tar.gz

I have changed the build procedure for linux to hopefully fix this.

Comment: yes it is debain 64-bit squeeze updated on 14th of april.

Comment: I'll give it a try as soon as I am back home. Thanks for the marvellous support.

Comment: Sadly no changes with that version

Comment: Could you open a bug on the biber SourceForge tracker? I think we need to move it to there to diagnose. This is very strange.

Comment: I'll do that as soon as I am at home. Best Markus

Comment: I have just booted a live CD of Debian Squeeze and I can run biber without any problem. What sort of update to the OS did you do?

Comment: it worked fine until I updated perl via 'apt-get update && apt-get upgrade'. BTW I opened a bug report on SF

Comment: For reference; The potential bug is tracked here https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3519958&group_id=228270&atid=1073792  It could be a bug in Debians new Multiarch move. A temporary fix in Debian Sid is to create a symlink `/usr/lib/libz.so.1 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a problem with some bad RPATHs hard-coded into some linux XML libraries which biber included. This meant that biber was using the OS libxml2 which it shouldn't have been doing. Wheezy has a very recent libxml2 which conflicted badly with the Perl XML::LibXML module. It's now fixed and shouldn't happen again in the future as the build process removes all RPATH settings from biber's own libraries (RPATH settings should never have been there in the first place). All binaries have been updated on SF.

Comment: Do you know whether the version in texlive is updated also? I have some weird behaviour with the version you compiled for us. (some second occurances of a cite produce empty brackets). Or sould I rather pick the binary from SF?

Comment: texlive is not updated - it probably won't be until version 1.0 Can you open a ticket about the issue? That sounds like a normal bug/issue than anything to do with the binary per se - it sounds too specific.

Comment: I'll do after submitting my thesis. Is the new version different from the one you compile us/ is it worth updating?

Comment: Version 1.0 is for use only with biblatex 2.0+. both are beta so finish your thesis first ...

Comment: I was referring to the version with the fixed path, not the 1.0 beta. I love risk but I am not nuts ;-)

Comment: No, the one I compiled for you chaps is exactly the same as the one on SF.

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to [Engines of Tex-Editors and Biber/Biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47553/engines-of-tex-editors-and-biber-biblatex), only the platform is different.

Do, from a shell,

```
rm -fr /tmp/par-6772656269
```

This should get rid of the precompiled libraries and create new ones.

However, this might be caused by a missing or misplaced `zlib`. Does the problem reappear after the `rm -fr` command?

Comment: Yes it does. That was the solution I have been referring to. And it is the reason why I opened the question since it doesn't work =-(

Comment: On my Ubuntu 11.10 I have `libz.so.1.2.3.4`, but I don't know to what Debian it corresponds. Did you try updating `libz`?

Comment: I cannot find libz in the package manager. I installed everything that looks alike, such as lib32z1 without any change

Comment: The path /usr/local/perl/lib/ does not exist at all. It looks like something changed in the perl installation on debian...

Comment: I am pretty sure, that the path to the perl installation has changed due to upgrade of perl from 5.14.1 to 5.14.2. Perl is now under:`/usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/` Sadly I do not have any idea where biber does get the path from...

Comment: Amazingly enough, for me the `rm -rf` trick worked `:)` (Ubuntu 11.04) - many thanks for noting it! Cheers!