# Why does using Greek break em-dashes?

Tags: luatex, fontspec, greek

I know the conversion of --- to an em-dash is an on-going problem with lualatex. But I don't understand why using Greek in one font should (afterwards) break conversion of 3 hyphens to an em-dash in another.

Here is my code:

```
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ednotes}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase]{TeX Gyre Heros}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Inconsolata}
\newfontfamily\myGk[Script=Greek,Scale=MatchUppercase,Ligatures=TeX]{Cambria}
%\newfontfamily\myGk[Script=Greek,Scale=MatchUppercase,Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}

\newcommand\textgreek[1]{\myGk\emph{#1}}

\begin{document}
\fontsize{11.5}{13}\selectfont


This is a test---to see if dashes are being converted to emdashes.

\textgreek{Ἐν ἀρχῇ ἦν ὁ λόγος}

This is a test---to see if dashes are being converted to emdashes.

\end{document}
```

For me, if I run the above code as is, the second "This is a test..." comes out with dashes instead of an em-dash. If I use the Linux Libertine O font for the Greek, I don't have the problem.

Can anyone tell me how I can use the Cambria Greek (which I prefer) without breaking em-dashes in the main font? I am using TeXLive 2012 with Mac TeXShop.

Comment: The problem with Cambria not rendering the `---` correctly is due to a bug in luaotfload.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

hold the definition local:

```
\newcommand\textgreek[1]{{\myGk\emph{#1}}} %  {{...}}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the solution is pretty clear as it is a little bit my fault. (Sorry!)

When I first posted my answer to your previous question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65141/getting-started-with-greek-and-hebrew-in-lualatex), I made a little mistake, which I corrected later. You, however, did not use the updated version of my answer. This mistakes seems to cause your present problem.

You need to use this:

```
\newcommand{\textgreek}[1]{\bgroup\myGk\emph{#1}\egroup}
```

You see, the fontcommands for the greek font are now enclosed by bgroup ... egroup. Without this, the Greek font is used **for the rest of the document** and not just for the few Greek words.

Since the em-dash is not part of your Greek font, it does not typeset it. I am currently not able to check my assumption, but I am pretty sure, this is it.

In effect, this is very similar to Herbert's solution, but -- imho -- more elegant and perhaps in some extreme cases even more secure to use.

Comment: Cambria **has** the em-dash, but with `luaotfload`'s `render=node`, it is broken (at the moment). With `render=basic` the em-dash in Cambria works fine.

Comment: The answer is not similar it is the same, `\bgroup ... \egroup` is _not_ different to `{...}`