# Pi, Kappa, Latin Small Letter Long S: problems with UTF8

Tags: unicode, font-encodings, input-encodings, sv-classes

I'm using [Springers *svmono*](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/svmono.zip?SGWID=0-0-45-72921-0) for a book with many mathematical symbols and special characters.

There are quite a few problems with characters that are simply not printed (using pdfLatex), so I tried to add utf8 support:

```
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

However, there are errors. This is a MWE (*svmono.cls* needed to make it run):

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% book.tex %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% sample root file for the chapters of your "monograph"
%
% Use this file as a template for your own input.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Springer-Verlag %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


% RE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}

% choose options for [] as required from the list
% in the Reference Guide

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
   # sin(π * t)
\end{verbatim}

Kudos (κῦδος)

\end{document}
```

Using **utf8x** I get:

```
ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---
\u-default-954 #1->\textkappa
```

Using **utf8** I get:

```
ERROR: Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:π not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

And I need characters more exotic than *pi* or *kappa* - like *latin small letter long s* e.g.

Comment: There's little hope to get different sets of characters in this way: LaTeX fonts have only 256 characters.

Comment: And couldn't you use `\pi ` instead of `π`, and similarly for the other symbols? You can do a Find&Replace in any good text editor.

Comment: @tohecz yes, but *\pi* doesn't work in verbatim environments, and there are quite a lot a rare characters for which I don't know the macro name (e.g. *latin small letter long s*).

Comment: @egreg Not sure if I understand you - must I change the font or the way/approach? I tried e.g. *\usepackage{ucs}* and then *\unichar{"17F}*, but all I got was a black square in the pdf instead of the infamous *latin small letter long s*.

Comment: @user17106 Couldn't you use some "cleverer" environment than `verbatim`? E.g. `alltt` or `listings`? (Disclaimer: I don't say that `verbatim` is wrong, but it simply does not interpret anything, and allowing the commands to be interpreted is one of the ways IMHO.)

Comment: @tohecz I already use *wideverbatim*, a customized *verbatim*, and its really essential for the book - can't change that. It would be already quite helpful if I find a way to have pdfLatex print these utf8 characters in normal text (outside *verbatim*).

Comment: Sorry, but it's 2012: Use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX. Both engines can handle Unicode natively.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Did you try it out before flaming? I was surprised how poorly LuaLaTeX handles this example. The main problem is that lmodern does not contain upright Greek characters or the long s. In any case, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65141/getting-started-with-greek-and-hebrew-in-lualatex might help to point you in the right direction since I agree that *without* LuaLaTeX you're pretty sure to be screwed. As for verbatim unicode ... boy, good luck with that.

Comment: @Christian: It is 2012 already, **you don’t have to stick to the default font** anymore.

Comment: I tried the second solution, because looks shorter. I found that can't be used with utf8 input encoding. Must be used utf8x.

Comment: @KhaledHosny What is it with 2012 that you guys keep pointing it out over and over? The question explicitly asked for lmodern and Martin Schröder made it sound as if you just have to change to LuaLaTeX and everything will be fine. It isn't. Not even a warning is issued BTW that some characters couldn't be printed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The long s (ſ) is accessible through the `TS1` fontencoding.
Depending on the frequency you need it in your text, you can use it

- with the `\longs` command or
- the `"s` command.

For written Greek text I'd use the [`babel`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel) package.
For Greek text in verbatim mode you can use the [`alltt`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/alltt) package and either the `babel` package again or (for single letters) the [`textgreek`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textgreek) package.
<sub><sup>Edit: I just read that you use a customized `wideverbatim` environment. Can you provide a definition? I coudn't find one.</sup></sub>

I have troubles with the Greek font encoding `LGR`.
Someone with a better understanding of font encoding might improve this answer.

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}

\usepackage[LGR,TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{alltt}

\def\longs{{\fontencoding{TS1}\selectfont s}}
\def\greek#1{{\selectlanguage{greek}\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont #1}}

\catcode`\"=\active%
\def"s{{\fontencoding{TS1}\selectfont s}}
\def\noLongS{\catcode`\"=12}

\begin{document}

\begin{alltt}
   # sin(\textpi * t)
   # sin(\greek{p} * t)
\end{alltt}

\noindent Kudos ({\greek{k~udos}) % κῦδος
\\
long s: Wach\longs tube\\
long s: Wach"stube\\
{\noLongS%
not a long s: Wach"stube}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I was able to compile properly your MWE (although simplified a bit) using the `textalpha` package instead of `textgreek`. Here is how :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % Note : option utf8 works also
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textalpha}

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
   # sin(π * t)
\end{verbatim}
Kudos (κῦδος)
\end{document}
```

So I obtain the following result :

[image: after compiling]

(Added:) Please note that the `textalpha` package seems to give better results than the `textgreek` one.

Comment: Sorry, I only had one bounty and one 'answered' choice, but after downloading two packages I could make your solution work too, and its to simple. Thanks.