# Hebrew shows no output

Tags: hebrew

I'm trying to type some Hebrew in my document, which is mainly in English and German. The document compiles, but there are no Hebrew letters in the output. The log shows lots of messages like

> Missing character: There is no ו in font frank!

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[combine]{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\makeatletter\let\l@hebrew\l@nohyphenation\makeatother
\usepackage[hebrew,english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{hebfont}
\usepackage{culmus}
\begin{document}
\R{וְאָהַבְתָּ לְרֵעֲךָ כָּמוֹךָ}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I'm not sure if `utf8x`results better choice than `utf8`, in the other hand, maybe the set `T1` of `fontenc` doesn't contains the Hebrew characters. Finally the error tells you that the font you're using hasn't the Hebrew character you need.

Comment: You probably need a `\selectlanguage{hebrew}` (I get a lot of errors with your example and I don't see where the font frank should come from so I have some doubts that your example is real).

Comment: If you are willing to use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX to compile, you can write in Hebrew very simply. If you use the `libertine` package for your font, you don't even need to select a Hebrew font or use any commands. You just type Hebrew unicode characters and it works out.

Comment: Thank you, `libertine` works perfectly!

Comment: @AndrewCashner: but you still have to mark directionality overtly (using `bidi`’s `\RL{}`), don’t you. Does it support *nikud*?

Comment: @JúdaRonén See this excellent answer, which shows how to do right-to-left just using `fontspec` in LuaLaTeX without `bidi`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65141/getting-started-with-greek-and-hebrew-in-lualatex . I don't actually know Hebrew yet, so I can't answer your second question, sorry.

Comment: @AndrewCashner: Thanks! It’s good to know LuaLaTeX can support bidirectionality internally. For now I’ll still stick to XeLaTeX+`bidi`, but I’ll definitely check LuaLaTeX out.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the [culmus-latex](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/culmus-latex/) package does not support Nikud by default and doesn't seem to like the `combine` option to `ucs`. If you remove that option and the Nikud, you example compiles just fine.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\makeatletter\let\l@hebrew\l@nohyphenation\makeatother
\usepackage[hebrew,english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{hebfont}
\usepackage{culmus}
\begin{document}
\R{ואהבת לרעך כמוך}
\end{document}
```

If you need Nikud, have a look at the [hiriq example](http://sourceforge.net/p/ivritex/culmus-latex/ci/master/tree/examples/hiriq/) from the culmus-latex source. It requires an additional file to map the Nikud symbols and using PostScript when generating output (you may later call `ps2pdf` to generate a pdf).

Disclosure: I maintain the culmus-latex package.