# AucTex does not export Hebrew to a pdf file

Tags: pdf, hebrew

I created the following bilingual LaTeX document in English and Hebrew.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

Hello

שלום

\end{document}
```

I exported the document to a pdf file using the key combination `C-c c`. The message `tex-evince-sync-view` appeared in the echo line as the export was in progress. When the file opened in Document Viewer, only the English word was visible.

I created the same document using LibreOffice Writer, exported it to pdf and double-clicked the resulting pdf file. The file opened in Document Viewer as before, but now both the English and the Hebrew words were visible.

I conclude that the problem lies in emacs/AucTex's pdf exporting mechanism, and that the problem is not due to the pdf viewer nor to the lack of suitable fonts on my system.

How can I fix emacs/AucTex to handle Hebrew correctly?

I use

- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- Emacs 24.3.1
- AucTex 11.87.2012-12-04
- DocumentViewer 3.10.3
- LibreOffice Writer 4.2.7.2

Comment: To typeset Hebrew from unicode input, the easiest way is to select a font with Hebrew unicode characters and compile with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{libertine}\begin{document} [Hebrew] \end{document}`; compile `lualatex file`. Don't know about the AucTeX part.

Comment: @AndrewCashner: Thanks, Andrew. How can I test whether I have LuaLaTeX or XeLaTex installed on my system?

Comment: Open a terminal and type `lualatex --version`.

Comment: @AndrewCashner: Thanks. I've compiled the document with the xetex engine and now the Hebrew letters show. However, the Hebrew words are written from left to right. Each word in itself looks correct, but the order of the words is wrong. Additionally, the Hebrew sentence is left justified whereas it should be right justified.

Comment: @AndrewCashner: Thanks, Andrew, but [this article](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65141/getting-started-with-greek-and-hebrew-in-lualatex) involves a spattering of Hebrew embedded in a predominantly English text. What if the entire document is in Hebrew?

Comment: XeLaTeX: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{libertine}\usepackage{fontspec}\usepackage{polyglossia}\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}` || LuaLaTeX: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{libertine}\usepackage{fontspec}\luatextextdir TRT`