# Greek and Hebrew in a single pdflatex babel document

Tags: pdftex, greek, hebrew

The following creates a perfect english document with some greek letters:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
English or \textgreek{ανηρ} text.
\end{document}
```

However, when I add this, It gets all upset about the hebrew characters being invalid characters.:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,hebrew,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
English or \textgreek{ανηρ} text.

And this גהר.
\end{document}
```

I have tried changing `And this גהר.`, guessing there might be something like `And this \texthebrew{גהר}.` but I guess there is not?

I wonder if anyone can point me in the right direction. (In case it matters, I am trying to stuff this in a beamer document. The above is jut my MWE)

---

This related question does not answer the question for Hebrew: [How to use both English and Greek (Tex Live & pdflatex) and even Hebrew easily in one document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339122/how-to-use-both-english-and-greek-tex-live-pdflatex-and-even-hebrew-easily-i?rq=1)

This related question uses polyglossa instead of babel for xelatex users [Perfect example document (template) for English, Greek and Hebrew (XeLaTeX)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354676/perfect-example-document-template-for-english-greek-and-hebrew-xelatex?rq=1)

Comment: I made the experience that pdfLaTeX+babel do not work well with Hebrew. I strongly suggest to use XeLaTeX+polyglossia.

Comment: @christian I am testing out texpad for iOS which doesn't support xelatex (they say its something about licensing, I'm not sure why).

Comment: Do you have a font for Hebrew in texpad?

Comment: I changed the inputenc from `utf` to `utf8x` and now I get the error that the Hebrew letters are not available in `T1` - so I think the problem are the missing fonts. Can you use `culmus-latex` in texpad?

Comment: Did you try `\usepackage[T1,HE8]{fontenc}`?

Answer (score 2):

I think the main problem is that the Hebrew fonts are missing. After installing the Hebrew fonts from [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/texarchive/language/hebrew/hebtex/unix/new), the following code compiles with pdfLaTeX (using texlive) without any errors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,hebrew,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
  English or \textgreek{ανηρ} text.

  And this \foreignlanguage{hebrew}{גהר}.
\end{document}
```

Please note that I also changed the input encryption to `utf8x`. Unfortunately, the above puts "גהר" at the right end of the line (since Hebrew is written from right to left).

A **really dirty** hack to solve this problem using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18577/93559) could be to use the `calc` package and define the command `\inlinehebrew` in the following way:

```
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand{\inlinehebrew}[1]{%
  \parbox{\widthof{\foreignlanguage{hebrew}{#1}}}{\foreignlanguage{hebrew}{#1}}}
```

Then

```
And this \inlinehebrew{גהר}.
```

generates the following output

```
And this גהר.
```

but, since it includes a `parbox`, it breaks many things and can only be used for very short texts.

Let me add two remarks in passing:

- Although not applicable in your situation: Because of the hassles involved in the above solution, I strongly recommend using Xe(La)TeX and `polyglossia` for writing Hebrew in LaTeX.
- Instead of using the (old) Hebrew fonts linked above, it might be better to use [culmus-latex](https://www.guyrutenberg.com/culmus-latex/) which uses the culmus fonts which in opinion look nicer.

Comment: I agree `polyglossa` and `xelatex` work a lot better, however sadly `xelatex` is not supported by `texpad` on iOS.

Comment: The above should work with pdfLaTeX. Does it work in texpad?