# Problem in compiliing LaTex with Hebrew

Tags: texlive, hebrew

I try to compile a simple test code with Hebrew one TexStudio:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}

% Add texlive-lang-other library to compile LaTex with Hebrew
\begin{document} 
שלום \L{World}!
\end{document}
```

But I get the following error message:

```
line 2: Font LHE/cmr/m/n/10=jerus10 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. \select@language{hebrew}
: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for(babel) the language `Hebrew' into the format.
```

Comment: You don't have the fonts installed. You can find them (somewhere) on ctan still. But I *strongly* recommend you switch to `xelatex` and `polyglossia` for Hebrew. You'll save yourself a world of pain. Look here for `xelatex` solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354676/perfect-example-document-template-for-english-greek-and-hebrew-xelatex/354679 and here for `babel`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365064/greek-and-hebrew-in-a-single-pdflatex-babel-document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly suggest using XeTeX. See [this post](https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2015/03/20/hebrew-with-xetex-example/) for an example. If you intend to write anything more than trivial however, [LyX](https://www.lyx.org/) would make it much easier for you, as there are lots of directionality quirks LyX takes care of automatically.