# How to write in Hebrew in this overleaf document?

Tags: fontspec, overleaf, babel, hebrew

I'm trying to write Hebrew text in the following document ([link)](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/acl-2023-proceedings-template/qjdgcrdwcnwp):

```
% This must be in the first 5 lines to tell arXiv to use pdfLaTeX, which is strongly recommended.
\pdfoutput=1
% In particular, the hyperref package requires pdfLaTeX in order to break URLs across lines.

\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% Remove the "review" option to generate the final version.
\usepackage[review]{ACL2023}

% Standard package includes
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{latexsym}

% For proper rendering and hyphenation of words containing Latin characters (including in bib files)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% For Vietnamese characters
% \usepackage[T5]{fontenc}
% See https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/encguide.pdf for other character sets

% This assumes your files are encoded as UTF8
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% This is not strictly necessary, and may be commented out.
% However, it will improve the layout of the manuscript,
% and will typically save some space.
\usepackage{microtype}

% This is also not strictly necessary, and may be commented out.
% However, it will improve the aesthetics of text in
% the typewriter font.
\usepackage{inconsolata}


% If the title and author information does not fit in the area allocated, uncomment the following
%
%\setlength\titlebox{<dim>}
%
% and set <dim> to something 5cm or larger.

\title{Instructions for ACL 2023 Proceedings}

% Author information can be set in various styles:
% For several authors from the same institution:
% \author{Author 1 \and ... \and Author n \\
%         Address line \\ ... \\ Address line}
% if the names do not fit well on one line use
%         Author 1 \\ {\bf Author 2} \\ ... \\ {\bf Author n} \\
% For authors from different institutions:
% \author{Author 1 \\ Address line \\  ... \\ Address line
%         \And  ... \And
%         Author n \\ Address line \\ ... \\ Address line}
% To start a seperate ``row'' of authors use \AND, as in
% \author{Author 1 \\ Address line \\  ... \\ Address line
%         \AND
%         Author 2 \\ Address line \\ ... \\ Address line \And
%         Author 3 \\ Address line \\ ... \\ Address line}

\author{First Author \\
  Affiliation / Address line 1 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 2 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 3 \\
  \texttt{email@domain} \\\And
  Second Author \\
  Affiliation / Address line 1 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 2 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 3 \\
  \texttt{email@domain} \\}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
This document is a supplement to the general instructions for *ACL authors. It contains instructions for using the \LaTeX{} style file for ACL 2023.
The document itself conforms to its own specifications, and is, therefore, an example of what your manuscript should look like.
These instructions should be used both for papers submitted for review and for final versions of accepted papers.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

These instructions are for authors submitting papers to ACL 2023 using \LaTeX. They are not self-contained. All authors must follow the general instructions for *ACL proceedings,\footnote{\url{http://acl-org.github.io/ACLPUB/formatting.html}} as well as guidelines set forth in the ACL 2023 call for papers.\footnote{\url{https://2023.aclweb.org/calls/main_conference/}} This document contains additional instructions for the \LaTeX{} style files.
The templates include the \LaTeX{} source of this document (\texttt{acl2023.tex}),
the \LaTeX{} style file used to format it (\texttt{acl2023.sty}),
an ACL bibliography style (\texttt{acl\_natbib.bst}),
an example bibliography (\texttt{custom.bib}),
and the bibliography for the ACL Anthology (\texttt{anthology.bib}).

\section{Engines}

To produce a PDF file, pdf\LaTeX{} is strongly recommended (over original \LaTeX{} plus dvips+ps2pdf or dvipdf). Xe\LaTeX{} also produces PDF files, and is especially suitable for text in non-Latin scripts.
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lc}
\hline
\textbf{Command} & \textbf{Output}\\
\hline
\verb|{\"a}| & {\"a} \\
\verb|{\^e}| & {\^e} \\
\verb|{\`i}| & {\`i} \\ 
\verb|{\.I}| & {\.I} \\ 
\verb|{\o}| & {\o} \\
\verb|{\'u}| & {\'u}  \\ 
\verb|{\aa}| & {\aa}  \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{lc}
\hline
\textbf{Command} & \textbf{Output}\\
\hline
\verb|{\c c}| & {\c c} \\ 
\verb|{\u g}| & {\u g} \\ 
\verb|{\l}| & {\l} \\ 
\verb|{\~n}| & {\~n} \\ 
\verb|{\H o}| & {\H o} \\ 
\verb|{\v r}| & {\v r} \\ 
\verb|{\ss}| & {\ss} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Example commands for accented characters, to be used in, \emph{e.g.}, Bib\TeX{} entries.}
\label{tab:accents}
\end{table}
\section{Preamble}
\begin{table*}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
\textbf{Output} & \textbf{natbib command} & \textbf{Old ACL-style command}\\
\hline
\citep{ct1965} & \verb|\citep| & \verb|\cite| \\
\citealp{ct1965} & \verb|\citealp| & no equivalent \\
\citet{ct1965} & \verb|\citet| & \verb|\newcite| \\
\citeyearpar{ct1965} & \verb|\citeyearpar| & \verb|\shortcite| \\
\citeposs{ct1965} & \verb|\citeposs| & no equivalent \\
\citep[FFT;][]{ct1965} &  \verb|\citep[FFT;][]| & no equivalent\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{citation-guide}
Citation commands supported by the style file.
The style is based on the natbib package and supports all natbib citation commands.
It also supports commands defined in previous ACL style files for compatibility.
}
\end{table*}
The first line of the file must be
\begin{quote}
\begin{verbatim}
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\end{verbatim}
\end{quote}
To load the style file in the review version:
\begin{quote}
\begin{verbatim}
\usepackage[review]{ACL2023}
\end{verbatim}
\end{quote}
For the final version, omit the \verb|review| option:
\begin{quote}
\begin{verbatim}
\usepackage{ACL2023}
\end{verbatim}
\end{quote}
To use Times Roman, put the following in the preamble:
\begin{quote}
\begin{verbatim}
\usepackage{times}
\end{verbatim}
\end{quote}
(Alternatives like txfonts or newtx are also acceptable.)
Please see the \LaTeX{} source of this document for comments on other packages that may be useful.
Set the title and author using \verb|\title| and \verb|\author|. Within the author list, format multiple authors using \verb|\and| and \verb|\And| and \verb|\AND|; please see the \LaTeX{} source for examples.
By default, the box containing the title and author names is set to the minimum of 5 cm. If you need more space, include the following in the preamble:
\begin{quote}
\begin{verbatim}
\setlength\titlebox{<dim>}
\end{verbatim}
\end{quote}
where \verb|<dim>| is replaced with a length. Do not set this length smaller than 5 cm.

\section{Document Body}

\subsection{Footnotes}

Footnotes are inserted with the \verb|\footnote| command.\footnote{This is a footnote.}

\subsection{Tables and figures}

See Table~\ref{tab:accents} for an example of a table and its caption.
\textbf{Do not override the default caption sizes.}

\subsection{Hyperlinks}

Users of older versions of \LaTeX{} may encounter the following error during compilation: 
\begin{quote}
\tt\verb|\pdfendlink| ended up in different nesting level than \verb|\pdfstartlink|.
\end{quote}
This happens when pdf\LaTeX{} is used and a citation splits across a page boundary. The best way to fix this is to upgrade \LaTeX{} to 2018-12-01 or later.

\subsection{Citations}



Table~\ref{citation-guide} shows the syntax supported by the style files.
We encourage you to use the natbib styles.
You can use the command \verb|\citet| (cite in text) to get ``author (year)'' citations, like this citation to a paper by \citet{Gusfield:97}.
You can use the command \verb|\citep| (cite in parentheses) to get ``(author, year)'' citations \citep{Gusfield:97}.
You can use the command \verb|\citealp| (alternative cite without parentheses) to get ``author, year'' citations, which is useful for using citations within parentheses (e.g. \citealp{Gusfield:97}).

\subsection{References}

\nocite{Ando2005,augenstein-etal-2016-stance,andrew2007scalable,rasooli-tetrault-2015,goodman-etal-2016-noise,harper-2014-learning}

The \LaTeX{} and Bib\TeX{} style files provided roughly follow the American Psychological Association format.
If your own bib file is named \texttt{custom.bib}, then placing the following before any appendices in your \LaTeX{} file will generate the references section for you:
\begin{quote}
\begin{verbatim}
\bibliographystyle{acl_natbib}
\bibliography{custom}
\end{verbatim}
\end{quote}
You can obtain the complete ACL Anthology as a Bib\TeX{} file from \url{https://aclweb.org/anthology/anthology.bib.gz}.
To include both the Anthology and your own .bib file, use the following instead of the above.
\begin{quote}
\begin{verbatim}
\bibliographystyle{acl_natbib}
\bibliography{anthology,custom}
\end{verbatim}
\end{quote}
Please see Section~\ref{sec:bibtex} for information on preparing Bib\TeX{} files.

\subsection{Appendices}

Use \verb|\appendix| before any appendix section to switch the section numbering over to letters. See Appendix~\ref{sec:appendix} for an example.

\section{Bib\TeX{} Files}
\label{sec:bibtex}

Unicode cannot be used in Bib\TeX{} entries, and some ways of typing special characters can disrupt Bib\TeX's alphabetization. The recommended way of typing special characters is shown in Table~\ref{tab:accents}.

Please ensure that Bib\TeX{} records contain DOIs or URLs when possible, and for all the ACL materials that you reference.
Use the \verb|doi| field for DOIs and the \verb|url| field for URLs.
If a Bib\TeX{} entry has a URL or DOI field, the paper title in the references section will appear as a hyperlink to the paper, using the hyperref \LaTeX{} package.

\section*{Limitations}
ACL 2023 requires all submissions to have a section titled ``Limitations'', for discussing the limitations of the paper as a complement to the discussion of strengths in the main text. This section should occur after the conclusion, but before the references. It will not count towards the page limit.
The discussion of limitations is mandatory. Papers without a limitation section will be desk-rejected without review.

While we are open to different types of limitations, just mentioning that a set of results have been shown for English only probably does not reflect what we expect. 
Mentioning that the method works mostly for languages with limited morphology, like English, is a much better alternative.
In addition, limitations such as low scalability to long text, the requirement of large GPU resources, or other things that inspire crucial further investigation are welcome.

\section*{Ethics Statement}
Scientific work published at ACL 2023 must comply with the ACL Ethics Policy.\footnote{\url{https://www.aclweb.org/portal/content/acl-code-ethics}} We encourage all authors to include an explicit ethics statement on the broader impact of the work, or other ethical considerations after the conclusion but before the references. The ethics statement will not count toward the page limit (8 pages for long, 4 pages for short papers).

\section*{Acknowledgements}
This document has been adapted by Jordan Boyd-Graber, Naoaki Okazaki, Anna Rogers from the style files used for earlier ACL, EMNLP and NAACL proceedings, including those for
EACL 2023 by Isabelle Augenstein and Andreas Vlachos,
EMNLP 2022 by Yue Zhang, Ryan Cotterell and Lea Frermann,
ACL 2020 by Steven Bethard, Ryan Cotterell and Rui Yan,
ACL 2019 by Douwe Kiela and Ivan Vuli\'{c},
NAACL 2019 by Stephanie Lukin and Alla Roskovskaya, 
ACL 2018 by Shay Cohen, Kevin Gimpel, and Wei Lu, 
NAACL 2018 by Margaret Mitchell and Stephanie Lukin,
Bib\TeX{} suggestions for (NA)ACL 2017/2018 from Jason Eisner,
ACL 2017 by Dan Gildea and Min-Yen Kan, NAACL 2017 by Margaret Mitchell, 
ACL 2012 by Maggie Li and Michael White, 
ACL 2010 by Jing-Shin Chang and Philipp Koehn, 
ACL 2008 by Johanna D. Moore, Simone Teufel, James Allan, and Sadaoki Furui, 
ACL 2005 by Hwee Tou Ng and Kemal Oflazer, 
ACL 2002 by Eugene Charniak and Dekang Lin, 
and earlier ACL and EACL formats written by several people, including
John Chen, Henry S. Thompson and Donald Walker.
Additional elements were taken from the formatting instructions of the \emph{International Joint Conference on Artificial Intelligence} and the \emph{Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition}.

% Entries for the entire Anthology, followed by custom entries
\bibliography{anthology,custom}
\bibliographystyle{acl_natbib}

\appendix

\section{Example Appendix}
\label{sec:appendix}

This is a section in the appendix.

\end{document}

About
```

If I just try to type in Hebrew (בבקשה) I get unicode errors, like `LaTeX Error: Unicode character ב (U+05D1)`

I tried adding

```
\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}
\selectlanguage{hebrew}
```

like in [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/hebrew-document-in-overleaf-writelatex-msmk-bbryt/vpfygfqnfjxs), but I'm getting tons of errors.

I also tried [this SO](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65141/getting-started-with-greek-and-hebrew-in-lualatex/620541#620541) solution, but it gave lots of errors as well. I'm not adding the error (20+) to save space, but can add if needed.

Comment: Are you compiling with xelatex or lualatex? You never mentioned in your question. On Overleaf, click on menu in the top left corner, then look at compiler. If it is pdflatex then that is probably why the errors are occuring. Change it to either xelatex or lualatex and see if the error persists, update us please

Comment: Apologies, not very familiar with these things. It says "pdfLaTex" under the compiler tab. If I switch to either xelatex or lualatex I get many other errors (you might not see them because I have other things in my file that I cannot add it, it's really a lot, like tables, figures, etc.)

Comment: Do you need several words or a couple of sections to be written in hebrew in your document?

Comment: @Penguin that's fine don't worry, it needs to be either xe or lualatex for font support on other languages characters so at least now that particular issue has been solved. I tried compiling it too and got lots of errors on Overleaf using your hebrew text, that template might need a lot of work to convert it to xelatex etc

Comment: @UdiFogiel Lots of words unfortunately