# Biber Compilation Error, Redux

Tags: compiling, biber, texshop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Engines of Tex-Editors and Biber/Biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47553/engines-of-tex-editors-and-biber-biblatex)

Encountering a problem discussed a few months ago (see [Dummies Guide to Biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63308/dummies-guide-to-biber)) but this time unable to resolve. MWE as follows,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authordate,noibid,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago} 

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

Here is the author \autocite{Ruhlman}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

But the output is unfortunately,

> Here is the author (**Ruhlman**).

When the desired output should be,

> Here is the author (Ruhlman 1989).

Similar to the above referenced thread, I obtain the following error message after running `biber`,

[image]

Terminal indicates that "permission denied" when I enter Alan Munn's suggested code. Any alternative suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try the method of [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47558/4427)?

Comment: @egreg: Thank you! I ran your terminal script as suggested on the recommended thread with my data source in `/var/folders/...` I also noticed (embarrassingly in hindsight) that when initially compiling with `LaTeX` (and before `biber`) the console output recommended that I run `biber` on test.bib. Perhaps this novice oversight may have been the primary problem? Regardless, the combination of both solutions seemed to have corrected the problem. Cheers.