# Biblatex problem, the list doesn't appear

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to customize my bibliography list, I have a problem.
I'm using Biber, because it´s mandatory for `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate`. The .bib file name is the same as in the code.

I have TexLive which includes Biblatex.

This is the error:

> LaTeX Warning: Citation 'averroes/hannes' on page 1 undefined on input
>   line 26.
>
> LaTeX Warning: Citation 'averroes/hannes' on page 1 undefined on input
>   line 28.
>
> (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/se-ascii-print.def)
>   [1]
>
> LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 31.
>
> (/Users/Isai/Documents/Info/Documentos/Estudios
>   estacionamientos/LaTex/.texpadtmp/Example.aux)
>
> LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
>
> Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file: (biblatex)
>   Example (biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{Untitled.bib}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field[strwidth=3,strside=left,ifnames=1]{labelname}
    \field[strwidth=1,strside=left]{labelname}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}
  }
}

\begin{document}
Filler text \parencite{averroes/hannes}

It's weird to text like this: \cite{averroes/hannes}

\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you run `biber` as it says? Also, are you sure `/` is allowed in keys? (I've just never tried this.) Otherwise, it is a bit hard to say since your code won't compile without `Untitled.bib`. Oh, and you needn't specify `backend=biber` twice ;).

Comment: If @cfr's comment is unclear, start with [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63875/8528); if that's not enough, see the answers to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/8528).

Comment: In addition to @jon look at  [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47553/engines-of-tex-editors-and-biber-biblatex)

Comment: If one changes `Untitled.bib` to `biblatex-examples.bib` (`biblatex-examples.bib` contains the entry `averroes/hannes`) everything works out fine after the usual calls to `pdflatex` and `biber`.